# Problem in download dropbox file from laravel

Tags: laravel, dropbox

I am using laravel-dropbox-driver package.
When i try to download file from droobox like
Storage::disk('dropbox') - >download($filename) ;
It throws an error 
Call to undefined method league/flysysten download

Comment: Could you post the entire error?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a required package, run the below command:

```
composer require spatie/flysystem-dropbox
```

This will install the required League Flysystem.